# "Satan" as a proper name

Tags: job, satan

I have heard that, in the entire Tanakh, "satan" always appears as "ha satan"--that is "the satan" and that it is at best a title, not a proper name so that even Jewish translators who write it in Job as "Satan" are technically incorrect. Is this view correct?